# Calcular o valor de uma multiplicação utilizando somente operadores de soma e subtração

Tags: python, algoritmo, matemática

Tentei escrever um programa no qual eu devo calcular o resultado de uma multiplicação através de operadores de soma e subtração somente.

Não consigo escrever nada que funcione, segue o código do mais próximo que cheguei:

```
var1 = int(input("Digite um numero: "))
var2 = int(input("Digite outro numero: "))
x = 1
y = 0
while x <= var1:
    print (y + var2)
    x = x + 1
    y = var2 + y
```

Comment: O seu código, embora tenha algumas coisas a melhorar, está funcionando perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

é tudo uma questão de lógica matemática mesmo, qual é a lógica por trás da multiplicação? você adiciona um número x vezes, então vamos programar:

```
x = 15
y = 0

for i in range(0, 5):
    y += x

print(y)
```

a lógica é simples, se eu quiser multiplicar 15 vezes 5 por exemplo, eu utilizo um for e adiciona numa variável (que inicialmente é 0) o meu valor a ser multiplicado

se você quiser pode aplicar essa lógica utilizando a mesma variável a ser multiplicada

```
x = 15

for i in range(1, 5):
    x += 15

print(x)
```

a única diferença aqui é que meu for vai acrescentar 15 sobre x 4 vezes, e não 5 como no primeiro exemplo, isso pois a variável já começa com 15, é como se já estivesse adicionado a primeira vez

- um adendo, nesse último exemplo, o número a ser adicionado, o número qual você quer multiplicar, nesse caso 15, precisa estar constante ali no for, por mais que a variável x seja definida como 15 no início você não pode cometer o equivoco de fazer x += x, pois após a primeira "rodada" do for, x vai receber 15 e se tornar 30, e se você ainda não estiver aprendido, o operador de multiplicação no python é *, por exemplo x *= 5 seria o equivalente ao nosso progama.

Answer (score 1):

A operação de **[multiplicação](https://matematicabasica.net/multiplicacao/#:%7E:text=Multiplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20%C3%A9%20uma%20das%20quatro,(ponto).)** nada mais é do que **adições sucessivas** de um determinado valor. Deste modo a operação de multiplicação pode ser montada da seguinte forma:

**Multiplicando x Multiplicador = Produto**

Neste esquema tanto o `multiplicando` quanto o `multiplicador` são chamados de fatores.

Em toda a multiplicação que seguem regras da **Álgebra Booleana**, a ordem de seus fatores não alteram o produto.

**OBS: ESTA REGRA SÓ É VÁLIDA PARA ÁLGEBRAS BOOLEANAS**

Neste caso a regra é valida, uma vez que estamos utilizando multiplicação no conjunto dos números inteiros. Embora isto seja verdade devemos ter bem consciência do que vem a ser de fato o multiplicando e o multiplicador.

1. Multiplicando é um número qualquer;
2. Multiplicador é a quantidade de vezes que será realizada as adições sucessivas.

Pois bem, vejamos os dois exemplos seguinte:

**Ex 1:**

**7 x 3 = 7 + 7 + 7 = 21**

**Ex 2:**

**3 x 7 = 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 21**

Em ambos exemplos o produto será o mesmo. Só que, quando formos montar o código deve ficar bem claro quem será o **multiplicando** - número qualquer - e quem será o **multiplicador** - a quantidade de iterações do laço de repetição.

Portando, reorganizando o seu código ele ficará:

```
var1 = int(input("Digite um numero: "))
var2 = int(input("Digite outro numero: "))
x = 1
y = 0
while x <= var2:
    y += var1
    x += 1

print(y)
```

Observe que o multiplicando será **var1** e o multiplicador será a variável que será incrementada, que neste caso será **y**. A variável **y** será responsável por incrementar as **adições sucessivas**.

Agora, se você preferir, pode utilizar uma implementação com o laço de repetição **for**. Neste caso, o código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
var1 = int(input("Digite um numero: "))
var2 = int(input("Digite outro numero: "))
y = 0
for x in range(1, var2 + 1):
    y += var1

print(y)
```

Observe que em ambos os códigos o **multiplicando** será a variável **var1** e o **multiplicador** será a variável **var2**.

Answer (score 1):

> <sup>*O seu código já funciona (para números positivos, pois se eles forem negativos, será necessário um ajuste, explicado mais abaixo). De qualquer forma, dá para melhorar um pouco...*</sup>

---

Basicamente, a multiplicação nada mais é que uma soma repetida várias vezes. Então é só fazer:

```
var1 = # ler o valor
var2 = # ler o valor

result = 0
for _ in range(var2):
    result += var1

print(result)
```

Ou ainda, pode usar [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) junto com uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
result = sum(var1 for _ in range(var2))
print(result)
```

Que basicamente é a mesma coisa.

Repare que não precisamos do valor da variável no `for`, por isso chamei ela de `_` (que é uma convenção do Python para indicar que a variável não é usada: ela só está aí para "satisfazer a <strike>burocracia</strike> sintaxe" da linguagem, que exige que se tenha uma variável ali). Mas como eu só estou interessado em somar o valor de `var1` uma determinada quantidade de vezes, tanto faz a variável do `for`.

Claro, tem ainda outro jeito - que deve ser mais ineficiente, por criar uma lista desnecessariamente:

```
result = sum([var1] * var2)
```

Basicamente eu crio uma lista contendo `var1`, e ao multiplicar uma lista por um número, eu gero outra lista contendo `var2` vezes o conteúdo da lista. No caso, teremos uma lista com o número `var1` repetido `var2` vezes, e basta somar tudo. Note que eu até usei multiplicação aqui, mas não foi entre os números ;-)

Mas como eu já disse, isso é desnecessariamente mais ineficiente, por gerar uma lista à toa (e se torna mais ineficiente ainda se os números forem grandes, pois aí estaremos gerando listas enormes sem necessidade).

---

**Só tem um porém**: este método só funciona se ambos os números forem positivos, ou se apenas `var1` for negativo. Mas se `var2` for negativo, aí o `range` já não funciona mais, então temos que fazer uma pequena adaptação:

```
# lê os valores de var1 e var2

if var1 < 0 and var2 < 0: # se ambos forem negativos, inverte o sinal (pois o resultado será positivo)
    var1 = -var1
    var2 = -var2
elif var2 < 0: # se somente var2 for negativo, troca de lugar com var1
    var1, var2 = var2, var1

if var1 > 0 and var1 < var2: # se var1 não é negativo e for menor, também troca com var2
    var1, var2 = var2, var1

# calcula usando um dos métodos acima
```

Se ambos forem negativos, basta inverter o sinal deles (já que o resultado será positivo).

Se somente `var2` for negativo, eu troco o valor dele com `var1` (assim, `var1` passa a ser o número negativo e `var2` o positivo).

Outro caso em que eu troco `var1` com `var2` é quando `var1` é menor (mas apenas se for positivo). Essa é uma otimização para o caso de `var2` ser muito maior: por exemplo, se `var1` for 5 e `var2` for 1 milhão, serão feitas 1 milhão de iterações para somar o 5. Mas se eu trocar os valores deles, farei apenas 5 iterações somando 1 milhão (claro que se ambos forem números muito grandes, não fará tanta diferença).

E se quiser, também pode incluir um outro caso, quando um dos números é zero, pois aí o resultado é zero e não há o que calcular:

```
if var1 == 0 or var2 == 0:
    # se um dos números é zero, nem precisa calcular
    result = 0
else:
    # usa o código acima para calcular...
```